# Will graha drishti ever go away?

Tags: astrology

Suppose someone is born with a Saturn-Sun conjunction or Saturn-Mars conjunction in their natal birth chart.  Will this ever go away in the person's lifetime?

It is said that people with debilitated Sun might have less luck in first half of life, but life will improve in second half.  Any similar concept for graha drishti?

Comment: How the combination itself will go away? that is permanent for this life. But the effects of that combination can be made to go away. There is that possibility.